# Cygwin - SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file

Tags: sql, database, shell, unix, cygwin

I am creating a shell script to spool db result. When i run the script i am getting SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sqlplus -s hr/hr  <<EOF
spool on;
SET PAGESIZE 50000;
SET COLSEP ",";
SET LINESIZE 200;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;

SPOOL /home/user/practice/regions.csv

SELECT * FROM regions;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

Comment: Is sqlplus is cygwin program ?

Comment: sqlplus is an windows executable provided by Oracle as part of an Oracle client or server install.

Comment: Make sure that the folder to which you are writing the spool file exists. Sqlplus will not create missing path components for you. Use `host mkdir -o path`, with a windows directory path. Use a windows format file name for the spool file. You can embed a `$(cygpath -w ...)` command in a shell here document. Remove `spool on` as it tries to open a default spool file. The `SPOOL <file>` command turns spooling on.